# HMAC encryption result different from JUnit test and Spring

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, hmac

I have some strange issue with my function. I'm trying to get a HMAC encrypted data from a secret key. 
I worked on a unit test to try my algorithm, and it worked fine.

Here is the code, with hard datas to make it easier to test :

```
public static String hmac(String parameters, String key) {
    String result = "";
    parameters = "PBX_SITE=1999888&PBX_RANG=32&PBX_IDENTIFIANT=2&PBX_TOTAL=1000&PBX_DEVISE=978&PBX_CMD=TEST TEST&PBX_PORTEUR=test@test.com&PBX_RETOUR=Mt:M;Ref:R;Auto:A;Erreur:E;Id:U&PBX_HASH=SHA512&PBX_TIME=2011-02-28T11:01:50+01:00&PBX_TYPEPAIEMENT=CARTE&PBX_TYPECARTE=CB&PBX_AUTOSEULE=O";
    key = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF";

    try{
        final String HMAC_SHA512 = "HmacSHA512";
        Mac sha512_HMAC = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA512); 

        //pack
        String input = key.length() % 2 == 0 ? key : key  + "0";
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i+=2) {
            String str = input.substring(i, i+2);
            output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
        }
        key = output.toString();

        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA512);
        sha512_HMAC.init(keySpec);

        byte [] mac_data = sha512_HMAC.doFinal(parameters.getBytes());

        //toHex
        result = String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, mac_data)).toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(result);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    return result;
}
```

When i call this function with my Unit Test, the result is fine :

```
String hmac2 = AboWebUtils.hmac(parameters, key);
```

9D47FFC1779013D1D26F92EE1C858AD7ECE5333106D4D61892BC683F640B061A72124F72A5B7BCD445767E347F9BA8ADE9A08A36791669E32E99C17975BD2FC2

When i call this method from y web app (Spring framework), i got a different result (wrong) :

```
AboWebUtils.hmac(parameters, key);
```

14BC65DEC5AF3CEED21F024D6A5665F6C8BDF90F956F8D327E0382A3A7F09ACEF557A2C5CE72F32D0CA2B3FBBE344CE5D2798526817E5647210D663AEA9BB899

I don't get why the results are differents. I am calling the same method, the parameters are even overriden for test purpose. I should get the same result. JUnit & Spring dont call the method with the same way or something like that?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Most probably different version of class is used. Try clean all and rebuild your app.

Comment: Hey Talex :) I tried to clean my projects, but the problem still occurs :(

Comment: When I try to run your code I get completely different output.

Comment: Also I don't like `(char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16)` it may result to illegal characters and later by transformed to something wrong in `output.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
        byte[] output = new byte[input.length()/2];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i+=2) {
            String str = input.substring(i, i+2);
            output[i/2] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
        }
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(output, HMAC_SHA512);
```

With this change I got result similar to your `9D47FFC1779013D1D26F...`

Comment: Oh god, indeed, with this algorithm, i have the same results from my unit test AND my web app. That seems strange for me, is it because of the risk of illegal characters you mentionned before?

Comment: Yes. At least it will have sense.

Comment: Yeah, i'm new to the site (at least as a poster). I voted up your answer, if it's the button you meant. :)